# custom time format in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, setting this line `{{movie.duration | secondsToHHMM | date:'HH:mm'}}` gives => 02:34 (2 hours and 34 minutes).  I would like to have the output to be '2H 34M' instead of 02:34 format.  How can I customize the time format in the placeholder?

'movie.duration', course comes from an ng-repeat, ng-repeat="movie in movies", btw

I'm brand new to AngularJS, your help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there isn't a filter option that gives you the desired output, I believe you can create a custom filter. I've never written myself, so I can't help further, but I think this is the direction you'll be heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional chars or strings in date formatting rules:

```
{{ movie.duration | secondsToHHMM | date: "HH'H' mm'M'" }}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date